# Indicators for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: unity, 12.04, indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)

Please post available indicators that work in new LTS Ubuntu version 12.04.

Most of indicators posted here: [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available) aren't available in 12.04

PS: although indicator-multiload can be run in 12.04, that patched work doesn't look like it belongs in Unity indicators however bold this may seem against all those votes in liked question - it's for gnome panel, it doesn't look at all as Unity indicator, IMHO

Comment: Please don't create a duplicate question. Just edit the old one to be correct.

Comment: How to do that? Many of provided indicators doesn't work in 12.04. I think it's good idea to provide just 12.04 working indicators. It's just a question and anyone can join

Comment: You can submit an edit to each answer to make them correct. We don't need a bunch of unmaintained list questions on the site.

Comment: Is linked question maintained? AFAIK < 25% work on 12.04 and at the end < 50% will work. Whatever, suit yourself, you are the boss

Comment: Questions are community maintained, if an answer is unmaintained it's because no one has updated it yet.

Comment: And who closed this question? Community that you refer to?

Comment: Yes, we flagged it to be closed because it's a duplicate. Please check out the FAQ, or if you have more questions post on meta.askubuntu.com

Comment: It's not a duplicate. It's about indicators that work in 12.04 and not some overall indicators. Question is precisely asked, and I don't need to read the FAQ to know that I'm wrong according you.

Comment: Please post your concerns on meta.askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

**CPU frequency indicator.**

Indicator applet for displaying and changing CPU frequency on-the-fly. It provides the same functionality as the Gnome CPU frequency applet, but doesn't require Gnome panel and works under Unity.

[image]

Link: [indicator-cpufreq](https://launchpad.net/indicator-cpufreq)

Answer (score 0):

**Ejecter**

Safely, easily remove external media. A simple menu that sits in the system notification area, providing you a quick way to unmount external peripherals such as usb pendrives, cd/dvd, external hard disks and so.

[image]

Link: [ejecter](https://launchpad.net/ejecter)