# How do I install the GNOME sensors-applet package in Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, indicator, sensors

I want to install sensors-applet onto my Ubuntu 12.04 computer.  The instructions on [this](http://sensors-applet.sourceforge.net/index.php?content=packages) (and other) webpages says to enter this command in a command terminal:

`sudo apt-get install sensors-applet`

This is a gnome applet and gnome isn't exactly obscure.  Why can sensors-applet package not be found?

Before you say "no", note that I was able to execute "gnome-panel" to add a bar/panel along the bottom of my desktop, add 8 cpu-frequency applets to the bar (one per CPU core), and add gnome-panel to my startup applications.  So I've already done the basics, and believe all I need now is to be able to download and install the sensors-applet to have that temperature applet available on the panel too.  See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152488/how-do-i-get-a-cpu-frequency-scaling-monitor-on-12-04).

Answer (score 4):

The `sensors-applet` package is not available in the 12.04 repositories. As a matter of fact, it is not even in 11.10.

The last release that had it was 11.04.

Comment: I guess so.  However, I installed gnome-panel on my 64-bit ubuntu 12.04 system, added the cpu-frequency applet to the bar/panel at the bottom of the desktop, and added gnome-panel into my startup applications.  When I restart, there is the panel complete with all 8 cpu-frequency icons on it - nice!  Since the cpu-frequency applet is just as obsolete as the sensors-applet, do you think the sensors-applet won't work?  I'd like to try it.  Why not.  Can you explain why this cannot work?  I don't understand.

Comment: It might work. You just can't install it straightaway from the 12.04 repo.

Comment: @honestann so, if you really want the sensor-applet, follow what izx has commented on your question.

Answer (score 3):

#### for 11.10 and earlier

The GNOME2 package for [sensors-applet](http://packages.ubuntu.com/sensors-applet) [image: Install sensors-applet] is available for the following Ubuntu versions **only**:

- [Hardy Heron 8.04 LTS](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/sensors-applet)
- [Lucid Lynx 10.04 LTS](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/sensors-applet)

#### for 12.04

Sensors applet 3.0. is not available from the 12.04 LTS repositories. You may be able to install from e.g. the following [ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) (untested by me):

```
ppa:darxus/sensors-applet
```

Alternatively you can always [download the source from GNOME](http://sensors-applet.sourceforge.net/index.php?content=source) to compile and install from there.

#### for 12.10 and later

The GNOME3 version of [sensors-applet](http://packages.ubuntu.com/sensors-applet) [image: Install sensors-applet] is is at present **only available** from the Ubuntu repositories for Ubuntu >= 12.10. Ubuntu 12.04 is not supported.

Comment: I installed gnome-panel on unity, and added the cpu-frequency applet successfully.  Now when I restart ubuntu (still unity), I now have the bar/panel at the bottom with 8 cpu-frequency applets on it, one for each CPU core.  Since that works, I bet this other temperature applet will work too.  So my question is still what I asked above, namely "how to install the sensors-applet package".  It's my own problem if it doesn't work after I've installed it.  Do I need to add a repository?  Does "no longer supported" == "won't work"?

Comment: @honestann: see edit but be aware of the dangers a ppa might have on system stability and security.

Comment: Hardy Heron is no longer a supported release.

Comment: If that one will be for GNOME3, don't I need to the one for GNOME2 given what I installed (gnome-panel)?

Comment: @DeanHowell: 8.04 LTS server support will end in April 2013.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu 12.04, this package is no longer available - unfortunately -.  There might be an equivalent *indicator* however.  There is a nice lice of indicators [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128896/indicators-for-ubuntu-12-04) with instructions on how to install them.  Many of these are sensor related and might cover your needs.  This might not be the answer you're looking for, but to be clear, sensors-applet is deprecated and not supported at all.

If you ***must absolutely*** have this applet, you may have to try and install the MATE desktop, though this is really overkill IMO.

Comment: I installed gnome-panel on unity, and added the cpu-frequency applet successfully.  Now when I restart ubuntu (still unity), I now have the bar/panel at the bottom with 8 cpu-frequency applets on it, one for each CPU core.  Since that works, I bet this other temperature applet will work too.  So my question is still what I asked above, namely "how to install the sensors-applet package".  It is my own problem if it doesn't work after I've install it.  Do I need to add a repository or something?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using ubuntu 12.04 or 11.10. For this sensors-applet does not exist.

See here http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=sensors-applet

Answer (score 1):

The package `sensors-applet` is only for Gnome2 and hence not available for Ubuntu after 11.04.

Have a look at [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available) to find an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I think that package is not available: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/sensors-applet

You can use System Monitor instead if you want something similar:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-multiload/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload
```

Refer to this question for more such indicators:

[What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)